# Can we make any implications about the internal structure of black holes from the 'chirp' that LIGO observed?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, singularities, ligo

Are there any implications about a black hole's internal structure we can make based on the [chirp](https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpl1/v/t1.0-9/12705573_10153931503438909_1455741693399938404_n.jpg?oh=ac0d075c0e24ade55e3c36b5aa89d681&oe=57360AD8) issued? For example that a black hole does in fact contain or does not contain a singularity rather than a super-dense form of matter/energy that we can't otherwise discover anything about due to the event horizon and information paradox?

Comment: I don't think you can even prove that black holes exist with LIGO experiment results, so I don't think you can say much about their structure from such results.

Comment: and this is a duplicate of 20 questions just for the last 2 weeks.

Comment: I did have a look and saw similar questions, but nothing that asked about the implications from the data rather than currently understood theories.

Comment: @rmhleo yes you can. The chirp matched the results of merging black holes to 5$\sigma$. If that didn't prove again the existence of BHs, I don't know what would.

Comment: @rmhleo The LIGO event is consistent with the gravitational inspiral of two compact bodies. Parameters of the signal give the masses of the bodies and the distance between their centers of mass when the signal switches from inspiral to ringdown. That distance is consistent with black holes and not with other theorized objects. Leaving aside the dicey word "prove" the signal *does* constrain our understanding of the world.

Comment: @KyleKanos You could actually design experiments to distinguish between a compact time dilated remenant of a large star and an eternal black hole. No one is interested in funding such an experiment because we all know we'd see the former. The latter is simply a simplified version that is easier to model theoretically. And gives very similar results for many situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any implications about a black hole's internal structure we can make based on the chirp issued?

No. The chirp data is consistent with the waves generated by the spacetime **outside** of two merging black holes. Therefore if there are two black holes, we'd get that data. Similarly if there were two compact and time dilated bodies such that the spacetime outside them were very very similar to the spacetime outside a black hole, then we'd get the same data (no data is perfect, so if the compact and time dilated body had a spacetime outside that was similar enough we'd get literally the same data).

> For example that a black hole does in fact contain or does not contain a singularity rather than a super-dense form of matter/energy that we can't otherwise discover anything about due to the event horizon and information paradox?

Waves don't come from inside the horizon, so we don't learn anything about the inside of the horizon. We don't even learn whether there is an inside to the horizon, let alone what, if anything, might be going on inside. We learn about the outside.

We learn that the outside is similar to the outside of a black hole. So the outsides of compact bodies are very similar (or possibly identical) to the outsides of black holes and produce waves like the outsides of black holes produce.

Comment: Ah thanks - it hadn't occurred to me that the waves would be generated outside of the event horizon - so still no violation of the information paradox. This seems to answer my question, thank you.

Comment: @Alex, but be absolutely clear, there are *no* other possible compact objects that have masses 30 times that of the Sun.

Comment: @RobJeffries An eternal black hole of 30 solar masses, and a compact time dilated remnant of a larger star are technically different objects. The latter exists and the spacetime outside it is very very similar to the spacetime outside the former. And when someone talks about the latter, that's what they mean when they say astrophysical black hole, even when they model it with the former. They are different. But the differences are often unimportant.

Comment: I'm misunderstanding something. The two objects have 30 solar masses and an orbital period that shrinks to around 1 second before they merge. What other astrophysical objects but black holes can they be?

Comment: Ok, your comment to Kyle explains. They're black holes by another name.

Comment: @RobJeffries There are astrophysical black holes and eternal black holes. The distinction between the two is hardly ever important, so when you say black hole you might literally refer to one while using the other to make your predictions. They are that similar. The eternal one has an event horizon and when you look at the metric outside is and the metric outside the astrophysical black hole they are very very similar metrics. The astrophysical one also has a metric inside. It is a time dilated version of the astrophysical things that became compact. The time evolution of the infall material

Comment: @RobJeffries The astrophysical one is the one we actually see in nature. You continue to see the material that made it up, just really slow and really red. It is, for instance, still getting a bit smaller in mass from the emission of electromagnetic radiation, but by such a small amount it is simpler to model it between two shells around it as if it were a black hole (too close and you bump against the actual matter, too far away and it's still the metric of the star out there becasue it hadn't collapsed enough yet) and in between the eternal black hole metric is fairly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational waves are produced **outside** the black hole event horizon.

**Background** One of the ways LIGO conducts their search for gravitational waves is by using [templates](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7949), so they match the known waveforms coming from binary black hole (or other compact object) systems with what is expected from theory.

**The story** After they made the initial estimates for the parameters, they ran a [supercomputer simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p647WrQd684&feature=youtu.be) (which shows pretty well where the gravitational waves are generated) to verify the results.

**What they can theoretically infer:**

- Lower limit for the mass of the graviton
- Mass of the binary black holes
- Spin
- Future observations: Velocity of gravitational waves (speed of light, fingers crossed)

Comment: There are other things they can infer but I guess these are the main ones for now?

Comment: about the velocity of gravitational waves, as best as i can tell (a mere electrical engineer that, at one time, knew how to design antenna array) that this latest LIGO result can only put a top limit on the wavespeed of gravitational waves at about 140% $c$.  when they infer the possible direction in the sky where the source came from, using the 7 ms delay between WA and LA, that was **assuming** the wavespeed was $c$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thanks, you're right. I added the velocity there since that's one of their goals, even if it was not accomplished by this detection.

Comment: i believe that, in order to nail the coffin shut on any other wavespeed than $c$, they will need a third LIGO detector somewhere in the world.  or somehow integrate these two LIGO detectors with the VIRGO detector in Italy.  i think then they will be able to unambiguously infer the wavespeed **and** the angle of incidence of the wavefront.  with two detectors i think they can derive one or the other, but not both independently.

Comment: Ah right, I do not think they will infer it from the angle, the angular resolution even with three detectors I suppose is really bad? A couple of ways to get around that is to use EM and/or neutrino signals to detect known events and compare.

Anyway, I didn't ask about the details but I heard the point about measuring speed of gravitational waves from a presentation given by one of the people working in LIGO.

Comment: Otto, if the time of arrival can be precisely determined (which means that all of the detectors are well synchronized), **simply** from the time difference **and** knowledge of the wavespeed, you can calculate a conical shape that points to possible directions of the source.  but you have to assume the wavespeed.  with 3 detectors and the same information, i think they can verify the wavespeed.

Comment: I agree with everything you said. I wanted to point out that there are sources that emit EM waves (easy to resolve the direction of the source), neutrinos (hard to resolve the direction) and gravitational waves (hard to resolve the direction) all at the same time.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something though. I suppose you mean it would be impossible to say for sure that the source is the same, even if the EM signature matched predictions for the same source?

Comment: i doubt that we will see much from an event 1.3 billion light years away.  but certainly if we see some spectacular event that emits light *and* we simultaneously detect a gravitational wavefront, then we can conclude that the gravitational wavespeed is $c$.

Comment: I know it may seem crazy but: http://www.ligo.org/science/Publication-S6CBCLowLatency/